# How do I send an email to an email address with an custom message

Tags: php, email

I wanted to send an email such as an confirmation email to an email address that the user has alredy specified in an input tag. Exampe:
I type in my email in an input tag and then I would recive an email at the address I entered in the input tag. Thanks, and If you know the answer could you possibly send me an code to paste in. (Im an php noob)

Comment: You should also know that stackoverflow is not meant to provide you codes for your projects but to help you when you tried and can't solve a coding problem. A simple google search would have given you an anwer or SO would have given you an answer while typing in your question

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 


$recipient = $_POST['email']; //recipient 
$email = "your@domain.com"; //senders e-mail adress 

if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && ($robotest == "")) { 

$Name = ($_POST['name']); //senders name 

$mail_body = !!!----> WHAT DO I PUT HERE <----!!!! 

$subject = "Porter Inquiry"; //subject 
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields 

mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header); //mail command :) 

} else {
  print "You've entered an invalid email address!";
}
?>
```

Comment: if you must copy a previous answer. You must learn to reference it

Comment: there is a change in this part of code that is the $recipient and $email.

Comment: Code dumps to not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. You should read, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.